# Method triggered two times but call one time , Firebase Request

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-lifecycle

I am building a social app for my studies and I have to use Firebase firestore to stock some informations about my app.

My problem is simple but I don't understand why I have this issue.
When the user creates an activity, that creates too a chat and a welcome message.
but my method (so my firebase request) is called two times.

```
private void createAct(SharedActivity SharedAct) {
    ActivityHelper.createActivities(SharedAct.getId(), SharedAct.getTitle(), SharedAct.getDescription(), SharedAct.getAdress(), SharedAct.getDate(), SharedAct.getPicture(), SharedAct.getMaxPartner(), SharedAct.getType(), SharedAct.getUserId()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            createWelcomeMess(SharedAct);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * To generate a new message in the  new activity
 * To launch the discussion in the activity
 */
private void createWelcomeMess(SharedActivity activityCreated) {
    if (!activityAlreadyCreated){
        MessageHelper.createMessageForChat("Bienvenue dans le chat de discussion", activityCreated.getId(), user).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Votre Activité est bien crée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: message created");
            activityAlreadyCreated = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                MainDashBoardFragment fragment = new MainDashBoardFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", ID);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack("frag").commit();
            }, 1000);
        });

    }
```

Can you give me some explainations and how to fix this issue?

What I have Tried already:

1. Initialize this method in the OnResume LifeCycle.
2. Change the Onclick method (with butterknife) to listen the onclick with the basic onclickListener.
3. Put some boolean to flag when the message is already created

```
    private void createWelcomeMess(SharedActivity activityCreated) {
    if (!activityAlreadyCreated){
        MessageHelper.createMessageForChat("Bienvenue dans le chat de discussion", activityCreated.getId(), user).addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Votre Activité est bien crée", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: message created");
            activityAlreadyCreated = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                MainDashBoardFragment fragment = new MainDashBoardFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("id", ID);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_frame_layout, fragment).addToBackStack("frag").commit();
            }, 1000);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). Besides that, how do you know if that method is called two times? And why do you say it is called only once?

Comment: my welcome message is created two time in firebase @AlexMamo. I will check this tutorial but my chat is ok. Everything else works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try snapshot listener. As documentation says it suppose to trigger only ones. In realtime database I had the same issue. And I switched regular listener to singleEventListener and it starts trigger only ones. So there suppose to be equivalent to singleEventListener but for Firestore. Im trying to avoid using firestore since it charges a lot for every read/write/update thats why Im save in firestore only users data which is general but rest info in realtime.

Here is code sample

```
query.addSnapshotListener(
    new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        // ...
    });
```